# How to make if condition in HTML sidebar in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a sidebar as follows in HTML,

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <h2 style="font-family: Verdana;">Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        
        <li><a href="dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> dummy1</a></li>
        <li><a href="dummy2.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> dummy2</a></li>
        <li><a href="dummy3.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> dummy3</a></li>
        <li><a href="dummy4.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> dummy4</a></li>
        
    </ul> 
    
  </div>
```

I need to check the username and show the tab.By using below code part I could get the current user logged in. I need to check whether below value is equal to John if and only if I need to show the tabs.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>
```

As an example,

```
if( htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"])=='John'){
             <li><a href="dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> dummy1</a></li>
            <li><a href="dummy2.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> dummy2</a></li>
            <li><a href="dummy3.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> dummy3</a></li>
            <li><a href="dummy4.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> dummy4</a></li>
}
```

Can someone show me how to achieve this with php and HTML?

Comment: You're nearly there - just wrap the PHP bits in PHP tags.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` should generally only be used for outputting.  `<a href="dummy1.php">` likely would be easier managed as `<a href="dummy.php?id=1">` then you only need 1 PHP file for all the dummies.. just take the GET value to determine which one it is.

Comment: @ADyson could you please help me as an answer?

Comment: @user3783243 dummy.phps are actually not as mentioned order..I just only used 1,2,3 likewise.Actually they have different names.no any pattern

Comment: `if( htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"])=='John'){
             <li>` should be `<?php if( htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"])=='John'){?>
             <li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there - just wrap the PHP bits in PHP tags.

Also as an aside, you don't need `htmlspecialchars()` unless you're outputting the value into a HTML document. When you're just using it in an `if`, you're not outputting it.

```
<?php 
if( $_SESSION["username"] =='John'){
?>
  <li><a href="dummy1.php"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> dummy1</a></li>
  <li><a href="dummy2.php"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> dummy2</a></li>
  <li><a href="dummy3.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> dummy3</a></li>
  <li><a href="dummy4.php"><i class="fa fa-plug"></i> dummy4</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: (With one exception, if the value at `=='John'` is not static but was stored with `htmlspecialchars` you will need to still encode. Data shouldn't be being stored with that function though)

Comment: @user3783243 Indeed. No-one should be storing data via htmlspecialchars though - if that's what is happening, it needs to be amended. htmlspecialchars() is only for use when generating _output_. Its main purpose is to protect data going into a HTML document from potential XSS attacks